# What is the time complexity of doing two binary searches to a sorted array that has been shifted to the right by some amount?

Tags: python, iteration, binary-search

I am given a *sorted array* that has been **shifted** to the right by some amount.

For example `[45,61,71,72,73,0,1,21,33,37]` ; which is `[0,1,21,33,37,45,61,71,72,73]` shifted to the right by 5 spaces.

We are also given a *target integer* that may or may not be in the array. If it is in the array, we are asked to return its index, otherwise -1.

My solution is using iteration to find the breakpoint of the sorted array, i.e. the point where it stops being sorted; in the above example this is at index 4.

Then to apply two binary searches: one to the first half of the array up to the breakpoint, and another one from breakpoint to the end of the array.

My question is, would the **time complexity** of this be `O(log(n))`, where n is the number of integers in the array? My understanding is that since we are using two binary searches, this will take a total of O(2 x log(n)) = 0(log(n))

For completeness, I have included my amended code below. To describe it simply, at each '`iteration`', I simply found the half of the array that DID NOT contain the `break point` and did a simple check (*comparing the target to the bounds*) on whether the target lies in this half; since this half is `fully sorted`, this is a O(1) operation. Please let me know if this DOES NOT achieve **time complexity** of `O(log(n))` - I believe it does now :)

```
def shiftedBinarySearch(array, target):
    start = 0
    end = len(array) - 1

    while start < end:
        middle = (start + end) // 2

        if array[middle] == target:
            return middle

        else:
            #the break lies in the second half of the list
            if array[start] < array[middle]:
                if target >= array[start] and target < array[middle]:
                    end = middle
                else:
                    start = middle + 1
            #the break lies in the first half of the list
            else:
                if target > array[middle] and target <= array[end]:
                    start = middle + 1

                else:
                    end = middle

    if start == end:
        if array[start] == target:
            return start

    return -1
```

Comment: To find your breakpoint is a linear search, i.e., O(n), which dominates the O(lg n) searches.  In order notation.  In real life practice: maybe not so much - depends on how much data there is.

Comment: If this is some kind of programming puzzle you're trying to solve: You probably want to reduce the O(n) component to something cheaper - preferably no more than O(lg n) which is (otherwise) your dominant cost.  So think about how you might do that.  Hint: You've already _got_ a search algorithm for finding an element in O (lg n) time.  So, can you conceive of finding the breakpoint of this array as some kind of ... search?

Comment: Imagine you've two indices `high` and `low` such that `a[high] > a[low]` and so the break is somewhere in between them.  What values can `a[mid]` have?  What does that tell you about where the break is?

Comment: Note that all these comments telling you that you can do the search in O(lg n) assumes that the elements are distinct.  If you have 1000,000 0s and one 1, then the only way to find the 1 is by linear search.  Any placement of the 1 fits the criteria.

Comment: @FrankYellin - that's a good observation! Which (as far as I can tell) applies in the following situation only:  Either the _smallest_ or the _largest_ element is duplicated and that element duplicated so many times it actually is more than half the elements of the array.  Is that correct?

Comment: @FrankYellin what if they are sorted :)

Comment: Thanks all for the hints, I've managed to logic it through!

Comment: @FrankYellin you're completely right- I forgot to mention that all integers are distinct indeed!